# get value of a different input field with jquery keyup

Tags: jquery

I have a form with 4 input fields

```
<div id="st5_one">
Top <input class="tb2" style="width:100px;" type="text" maxlength="3"   name="margin_top" placeholder="Margin top" value="5"> % 
Right <input class="tb2" style="width:100px;" type="text" maxlength="3" name="margin_right" placeholder="Margin right" value="5"> % 
Bottom <input class="tb2" style="width:100px;" type="text" maxlength="3" name="margin_bottom" placeholder="Margin bottom" value="5"> % 
Left <input class="tb2" style="width:100px;" type="text" maxlength="3" name="margin_left" placeholder="Margin left" value="5"> %
</div>
```

in my code and I am trying to get the values from all the fields when the value is changed in any of the fields

```
jQuery('input[name=margin_right]') .keyup(function(){
   //get the value in the input box
   var vl = jQuery(this).val();
   var image_right = (parseInt(vl))
   var image_top = $('#margin_top').val(); 
   alert("top is " + image_top)
   var image_top = jQuery('input[name=margin_top]').val();
   alert("top is " + image_top)
});
```

but I always get undefined for the `image_top` value. I am getting the value thats been input in the margin_right field.

Comment: Are you sure the second `alert` shows `undefined`? The first `alert` should show `undefined` as the target element doesn't have an ID attribute, it returns an empty collection and `val` returns `undefined`.

Comment: It looks like you're assigning image_top a value in the fifth line even though I don't see an ID for you to call it by. Have you tried removing that line to see what happens? Just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working one on jsfiddle. You specify the wrong target element. You used ID as a target element but your input dont have ID

```
https://jsfiddle.net/c8ms2ugo/
```

Example code

HTML

```
<div id="st5_one">
Top 
<input id="top-input" class="tb2" style="width:100px;" type="text" maxlength="3" name="margin_top" placeholder="margin top">%

Right 
<input id="right-input" class="tb2" style="width:100px;" type="text" maxlength="3" name="margin_right" placeholder="margin right" value="5">%

Bottom <input id="bottom-input" class="tb2" style="width:100px;" type="text" maxlength="3" name="margin_bottom" placeholder="margin bottom" value="5">%

Left <input id="left-input" class="tb2" style="width:100px;" type="text" maxlength="3" name="margin_left" placeholder="margin left" value="5">%
</div>
```

Javascript

```
jQuery('input[name=margin_right]') .keyup(function(){
   //get the value in the input box
   var vl = jQuery(this).val();
   var image_right = (parseInt(vl))

   var image_top = $('#top-input').val(); 
   alert('Top is ' + image_top)

   var image_bottom = $('#bottom-input').val(); 
    alert('Bottom is ' + image_bottom)

       var image_left = $('#left-input').val(); 
    alert('Left is ' + image_left)
});
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help, I can see exactly where I went wrong now you've pointed it out. This works perfectly

Comment: Please mark this post as answer if u think this post help u.